Using open-line with a negative argument?
When you type C-o (open-line), it opens a newline without moving the point; with a positive prefix, it opens that many newlines.
I expected that you can give the command a negative argument and then it opens lines above the current line and leaves the point in place.  But a negative argument results in an error message:

Repetition argument has to be non-negative

Is there a reason for this?  Why shouldn't open-line be able to open lines above the current line?  It would be a much more elegant solution than, for example, this answer for inserting lines above.
EDIT: This is probably very amateurish, but does what I want:
(defun my-open-line (n)
  "Insert a newline and leave point before it.
If there is a fill prefix and/or a `left-margin', insert them on
the new line if the line would have been blank. With arg N,
insert N newlines.  If N is negative, insert new lines above the
current line."
  (interactive "*p")
  (let* ((do-fill-prefix (and fill-prefix (bolp)))
         (do-left-margin (and (bolp) (> (current-left-margin) 0)))
         (loc (point-marker))
         ;; Don't expand an abbrev before point.
         (abbrev-mode nil))
    ;; Addition: negative prefix argument
    (when (< n 0)
      (forward-line 0)
      (newline (abs n))
      (goto-char loc)
      (while (< n 0)
        (cond ((bolp)
               (if do-left-margin (indent-to (current-left-margin)))
               (if do-fill-prefix (insert-and-inherit fill-prefix))))
        (forward-line -1)
        (setq n (1+ n)))
      (goto-char loc)
      (end-of-line)
      (scroll-up (abs n)))
    (when (> n 0)
      (newline n)
      (goto-char loc)
      (while (> n 0)
        (cond ((bolp)
               (if do-left-margin (indent-to (current-left-margin)))
               (if do-fill-prefix (insert-and-inherit fill-prefix))))
        (forward-line 1)
        (setq n (1- n)))
      (goto-char loc)
    ;; Necessary in case a margin or prefix was inserted.
      (end-of-line))
    ))



Is there a reason for this?

Yes.  As the error says, the argument is being treated as a "Repetition argument" which says how many times to do a particular thing, and it is nonsensical to do a thing a negative number of times.
The error comes from the call to (newline arg) which inserts ARG newlines.

Why shouldn't open-line be able to open lines above the current line?

No reason I can think of, and your suggestion seems like a perfectly reasonable interface for doing so.  You could submit that as a feature request or a patch.  Use M-x report-emacs-bug in either case.

Thanks! So it may just be a matter of inserting (when (< n 0) (forward-line 0) (newline (abs n)) (goto-char loc)) before (newline n) in the function -- at least I think I don't have to worry about left-margin and fill-prefix when inserting lines above the current line?

I think you still need to account for margins and prefixes, the same as before.  Possibly the only difference is which side of the opened gap point should end up on at the end, but I'd need to read the code more carefully.  Probably scroll-up by N when you're done, as well.

That’s simply the way it was written. If you want it to do something else, extend it or rewrite it.

This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - From Review
